# Car_Availability - What does the attribute "BS" indicate? ie. gallons, liters, no. of bags

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to identity what the the BS attribute defines for the boot size in a Car_Availablity response.

e.g.

```
\<nonNumericalAttributes\>  
\<attributeType\>BS\</attributeType\>  
\<attributeDescription\>3\</attributeDescription\>  
\</nonNumericalAttributes\>
```

Is it gallons, liters, no. of bags or something else?

I received the expected response as per the documentation.

Comment: Find a vehicle you are familiar with and see what figure it gives you. If the figure is very large it's probably litres volume. If it's small it may be gallons volume. If the figure is very small then it maybe bags but if you're familiar with the vehicle you can judge for yourself. 

They should have some documentation outlining this.

Comment: For questions related to Enterprise APIs we suggest you to get in touch with your account manager. In this channel we only provide support for Self-Service APIs.